# How to install OpenResty on Amazon Linux

Tags: nginx, web-server, openresty

I'm trying to install OpenResty on Amazon Linux but not having much luck.

I've followed the instructions on the website for installation using yum here: https://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html

but am getting the following error:

`https://openresty.org/package/centos/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, my bad. Turns out I was using the Centos repo. Needed to use the Amazon repo:

`sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://openresty.org/package/amazon/openresty.repo`